# To distinguish variable name from DB field name in Python

Tags: python, postgresql-9.4

Code

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
def store_values_to_pg94(file_size, connection): 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        INSERT INTO measurements
        (file_size) 
        VALUES (file_size)
```

where the field name of the column in PostgreSQL 9.4 is `file_size` but the variable name is also `file_size` in Python.

How can you avoid this kind of conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code from your example does not compile, i.e. it is not valid python. `cursor.execute()` accepts a string and an optional set of arguments that are expanded into the string according to the database module's [`paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle).

In fact, when using the [`DBAPI`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), your problem does not even surface, because SQL syntax and python syntax are completely separate.

If you are using `psycopg2` to access PostgreSQL, `paramstyle` is `pyformat`, hence

```
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO measurements (file_size) VALUES (%(file_size)s);',
    file_size=file_size # pass variable file_size as named parameter file_size
);
```

As you can see, you specify the SQL query and leave placeholders for the values that you want to pass in from python code.

If `paramstyle == 'pyformat'`, it is also possible to use positional parameters:

```
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO measurements (file_size) VALUES (%s);',
    file_size # pass variable file_size as positional parameter
);
```

Note that different database access modules implement different `paramstyle`'s and need different parameter placeholders (or a suitable wrapper).

All parameter substitution implementations are expected to properly escape their arguments according to the rules of the database backend, which is a nice and important feature as you don't have to manually escape your data.

Comment: I am using `psycopg2`. Which style is default in `psycopg2`? The latter style is easier to read than the former. However, if there is autoescape only in the former, then it must be better.

Comment: `psycopg2` accepts both (e.g. it properly implements `paramstyle == pyformat`) and both versions do autoescaping.

Comment: I think the biggest advantage of the former is that it is much clearer if you have many parameters to INSERT into the database so you can easily avoid mistakes this way. So I stick to the first one.